# Unexpected Search and Replace Behaviour - Neovim

Tags: vim

So I've got a load of LaTex tables with this heading:

```
Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes
```

That I want to replace with this heading:

```
Signal Name     & Value & Time ($\si{\nano\second}$)    & Duration ($\si{\nano\second}$)    & Notes
```

So I've written this command:

```
:%s/Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes/Signal Name\t& Value\t& Time($\\si{\\nano\\second}$)\t& Duration ($\\si{\\nano\\second}$)\t& Notes/g
```

But for some reason that I don't understand, it produces this output:

```
Signal Name Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes Value    Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes Time($\si{\nano\second}$)    Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes Duration ($\si{\nano\second}$)   Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes Notes
```

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: can you share what Output you needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the replacement text of a substitution command, `&` means the matched text. If you want to replace with a literal ampersand, use `\&`.

This should do the trick:

```
:%s/Signal Name & Value & Time & Notes/Signal Name\t\& Value\t\& Time($\\si{\\nano\\second}$)\t\& Duration ($\\si{\\nano\\second}$)\t\& Notes/g
```